# How to create bootstrap switch

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

One of my web designer given template for making `bootstrap switch`.I compiled it and rendered on top of page.it's displaying `checkbox`.

template Code:

```
 <script id="switchTemp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="span16 mr1 headerToggleDiv" style="height:42px;">
    <div class="switch switch-square pull-right" data-off-label="1" data-on-label="2"><input type="checkbox" id="switchBox"/></div>
    </div> 
</script>
```

using [this](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/), I tried in the following way.

```
  $('#switchBox').wrap('<div class="switch switch-square pull-right has-switch" />').parent().bootstrapSwitch();
```

getting small with default names(on,off),like in the following way.

[image]

I want in the following way.

[image]

I want `1,2` instead of `on,off` as a labels.

can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the script tag and use the below code to get 1 and 2 for On and Off.

```
 <div class="make-switch pull-right" data-on-label="1" data-off-label="2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switchBox"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: If I mention without script tag,it will render while page loading time.But I want to render switch once user change dropdown value. I have a dropdown list in my application. based on dropdown value,I want to render that.So As per I know it shold be in `script` tag because it's a template so wherever I want I will render it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for your work:

http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

Comment: I seen that link,what I tried that to from that link only.I can't able to fix that as per my requirements.